# Separate copy buttons to copy separate input fields without redundancies

Tags: javascript, function, input, copy

I have this (which I know is wrong):

```
function copy() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("copy_");
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
function copy2() {
    var copyText2 = document.getElementById("copy_2");
    copyText2.select();
    copyText2.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
    document.execCommand("copy2");
}
```

And it links to these:

```
<ol>
<li><p>Open Terminal and change directory to /test/:</p><input type="text" value="cd /Users/test/" id="copy_" disabled><button onclick="copy()">Copy</button></li>

<li><p>Make a directory:</p><input type="text" value="mkdir .test" id="copy_2" disabled><button onclick="copy2()">Copy</button></li>
</ol>
```

I was told my some coworkers to use event objects and `querySelectorAll` but I am not super sure how to incorporate this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about using event objects and querySelectorAll in this case.

But you have 2 similar methods that have a difference in the "id" of the element.

Create a method that will take the "id" of the element as a function parameter

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kj6axs4f/)

```
function copy(id) {
    var copyText = document.getElementById(id);
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
```